# Installing Visual C++ Redistributable 2012 64-bit in Wine on Ubuntu 64-bit dist

Tags: ubuntu, 64-bit, wine, dll

This is a known bug in Wine for 64-bit systems that the 2012 redist does not play well. I am running 14.04 64-bit. I need a pure 64-bit because of the program I am trying to install (Illustrator CC 64-bit).

I however *really* need it to work and I can even go to the lengths of manually moving `dll` files to do so. I have tried installing the following with wine but it doesn't work (does not start). [Here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) is a link to the file.

I'm now trying to extract the `dll`'s manually with `cabextract`. I extract the first wave of files as shown below:

[image]

The I extract both `a2` and `a3` as shown below:

[image]

[image]

I am now stuck, I do not know what to do now, been googling but noting shows up! (I am guessing I need to compile it into `dll`'s or something).

Comment: Do you have acess to a Visual Studio installation (maybe in a VM or something)?  If so, you can get the files you need there.  See [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293565.aspx).

Comment: @heavyd Hello! I keep reading people state "and get the files". *Which* files? Noone states which files so it's pretty hard to collect them when I do not know which ones! Do you know?

Comment: The linked article does cover that topic briefly, and also links to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kche8ah.aspx) which goes into more depth.